# Create User in InfluxDB v2 with role owner or assign role to a user later

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2

I was wondering if someone know if there is a way to use the InfluxDB v2 cli to create a user, assign to a organization and assign the role owner or change the role of a user later.

It seems that there is an API option but not at the CLI.

Also in the UI there seems to be no way to change the role of a user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a little bit tricky and not self explaining but this command here does the job:

```
influx auth create --all-access -u <userNeedingPermission> -o <theorg>
```

The user will than not be marked as owner but has complete rights on the platform.